# Getting lengthmenu value from datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have the following option as part of:

```
"lengthMenu": [[10, 20, 50, 100, -1], [10, 20, 50, 100, "All"]],
```

and I'm attempting to get the value selected for lengthMenu. However, after looking through the jquery API I cannot seem to find anything to get this value after it has been changed. Any possible solutions you guys can think of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [DataTables Documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/api/page.info()) has what you are looking for! The `page.info()` function will return a lot of different information about the paging of a DataTable, including the number of records shown on each page (the selected value for lengthMenu).

Here's a list of all the objects that will be returned by the `page.info()` call (all the things you can reference like how the above example does:

```
{
    "page": 1, //current page (0 based index)
    "pages": 6, //total number of pages
    "start": 10, //index of first element on page
    "end": 20, //index of last element on page
    "length": 10, //lengthMenu setting - this is what you want -
    "recordsTotal": 57, //total number of records
    "recordsDisplay": 57, //total number of records to display after filtering
    "serverSide": false //whether or not serverside processing is used
}
```

With all this in mind, what you actually want will look like this

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable(); //note that you probably already have this call
var info = table.page.info();
var lengthMenuSetting = info.length; //The value you want
```

All of this (in more detail and with some examples) is availiable at the link provided above.

**EDIT:** Actually, if *all* you want is the page length, you can use `table.page.len()` to just get the length of the page, instead of getting `table.page.info().length`.

Comment: Up-voted this answer because it works when you have multiple tables on a page.

Answer (score 0):

I thing you should use [aLengthmenu](http://legacy.datatables.net/ref) not lengthmenu

```
$('#table_id').DataTable( {
   "aLengthMenu": [[10, 20, 50, 100, -1], [10, 20, 50, 100, "All"]]
});
```

Comment: aLengthmenu is just the pre 1.10 DataTables option; there's no reason to use it if you're using DataTables 1.10+

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the answer by Chris H is correct and works, another possible solution was $("select").val() as I eventually found out.

Thanks for all the help everyone, I tried looking around online for the answer to this problem but couldn't find much. Hopefully these answers will help others out in the future.

Comment: One thing I'd recommend is that if you are having issues with DataTables search around on the DataTables forums themselves, or ask a question on them. The author of the plugin is really good about answering questions within a couple days.

Answer (score 0):

```
lengthMenu: [
  [10, 25, 50,100, -1],
  [10, 25, 50,100, 'All']
  ],
  "initComplete": function (settings, json) {
    var recordsTotal = $('#Example').DataTable().ajax.json().recordsTotal;
    $('select[name="Example_length"] option:contains("All")').val(recordsTotal);
  }
```